# DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION language hints

Tags: ocr, google-vision

I am using Google Cloud Vision's API DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION to extract text of multiple languages. I am trying to use the ImageContext feature to provide language hints as given [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/ImageContext). Can anyone tell me how to make use of it?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide a language hint string by specifying one of the languageHints codes from this page: https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages